# Couldn't upload the file getting Required request part 'fileImage' is not present

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

I have added image column to my existing table where I want to add image but after changing code in controller class, it didn't add the image instead I get : org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'fileImage' is not present.

should I change java script code on html form ?

1.Controller Class

```
@PostMapping("/employees")
    public String saveEmployee(@Valid @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee,
            BindingResult bindingResult, @RequestParam("fileImage") MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException
    {                                       
        //Here, we r using ModelAttribute to directly bind form data to the employee object.
        
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
        {
            return "create_employee";
        }
        else
        {
            String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
            employee.setImage(fileName);
            Employee savEmployee = employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
            
            String uploadDir = "/employee-images/" + savEmployee.getId();
            Path uploadPath = Paths.get(uploadDir);
            
            if(!Files.exists(uploadPath)) {
                Files.createDirectories(uploadPath);
            }
            
            try (InputStream inputStream = multipartFile.getInputStream()) {
                Path filePath = uploadPath.resolve(fileName);
                Files.copy(inputStream, filePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING); 
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IOException("Could not save uploaded file: " + fileName);
            }
            
            
            employeeService.saveEmployee(employee);
            return "redirect:/employees";
        }
    }
```

2.HTML Form

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Employee Management System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" 
      crossorigin="anonymous">

<style type="text/css">
    span {
        color: red;
        font-style: italic;
    }
    option {
  margin: 0.5em;
}
</style>

<style type="text/css">
    /* a:active {
        color: white;
    }
    a:visited {
        color: blue;
    } */
    a {
        display: blue;
    }
</style>
          
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Employee Management System</a>

  <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="changeable" th:href = "@{/employees}">Employee Management</a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>


    <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/employeesproject}">Employee Project</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>

<br>
<br>
    
    <div class = "container">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 container justify-content-center-center card">
                <h1 class = "text-center"> Create New Employee </h1>
                <div class = "card-body" >
                    <form th:action="@{/employees}" th:object = "${employee}" method="POST"
                            enctype="multipart/form-data"
                            style="max-width: 400px; margin: 0 auto;">
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label> Employee Image </label> 
                            <input
                            type = "file"
                            name = "fileImage"
                            th:field = "*{image}"
                            class = "form-control"
                            id = "fileImage"
                            accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
                            />  
                            <img id="thumbnail" alt="Logo Preview">
                        </div>  
                        <div>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            $(document).ready(function() {
                                $('#fileImage').change(function() {
                                    showImageThumbnail(this);       
                            });
                                
                            function showImageThumbnail(fileInput) {
                                file = fileInput.files[0];
                                reader = new FileReader();
                                
                                reader.onload = function(e) {
                                    $('#thumbnail').attr('src', e.target.result);
                                };
                                
                                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                            }
                                                
                        </script>
                            
                        </div>
                    
                        
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label> Employee First Name </label>    
                            <input
                            type = "text"
                            name = "firstName"
                            th:field = "*{firstName}"
                            class = "form-control"
                            placeholder = "Enter Employee First Name"
                            />  
                            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('firstName')}" th:errors="*{firstName}">Name error</span>      
                        </div>  
                        
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label> Employee Last Name </label> 
                            <input
                            type = "text"
                            name = "lastName"
                            th:field = "*{lastName}"
                            class = "form-control"
                            placeholder = "Enter Employee Last Name"
                            />  
                            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('lastName')}" th:errors="*{lastName}">Name error</span>                    
                        </div>  
                        
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label> Employee Email </label> 
                            <input
                            type = "text"
                            name = "email"
                            th:field = "*{email}"
                            class = "form-control"
                            placeholder = "Enter Employee Email"
                            />  
                            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('email')}" th:errors="*{email}">Email error</span>                 
                        </div>  
                        
                        
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label> Employee Skills </label>    <br>
                            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                            <input type="checkbox" th:field = "*{skills}" class = "selectupto3" name = "skills" value="Java" />Java <br>
                            <input type="checkbox" th:field = "*{skills}" class = "selectupto3" name = "skills" value="Python" />Python <br>
                            <input type="checkbox" th:field = "*{skills}" class = "selectupto3" name = "skills" value=".Net" />.Net <br>
                            <input type="checkbox" th:field = "*{skills}" class = "selectupto3" name = "skills" value="Kotlin" />Kotlin <br>
                            <input type="checkbox" th:field = "*{skills}" class = "selectupto3" name = "skills" value="C" />C <br>
                            <input type="checkbox" th:field = "*{skills}" class = "selectupto3" name = "skills" value="Ruby" />Ruby <br>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            var limit = 3;
                            var checked = 0;
                            $('.selectupto3').on('change', function() {
                              if($(this).is(':checked'))
                                checked = checked+1;

                              if($(this).is(':checked') == false)
                                checked = checked-1;

                              if(checked > limit) {
                                this.checked = false;
                                checked = limit;
                              }
                            });
                            </script>
                            
                            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('skills')}" th:errors="*{skills}">skill error</span>   
                    
                        </div>  
                        
                            
                            
                        
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label>  Employee Gender </label>
                            <input type="radio" th:field = "*{gender}" name = "gender" value="Male" />Male
                            <input type="radio" th:field = "*{gender}" name = "gender" value="Female" />Female
                            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('gender')}" th:errors="*{gender}">gender error</span>  
                        </div>
                        
                    
                        
                        
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label>  Employee Married? </label>
                            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
                            
                            <input type="checkbox" th:field = "*{marriage}" class = "selectOnly" name = "marriage" value="Married" />Married
                            <input type="checkbox" th:field = "*{marriage}" class = "selectOnly" name = "marriage" value="Un-Married" />Un-Married
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            $('.selectOnly').on('change', function() {
                                $('.selectOnly').not(this).prop('checked', false);
                            });
                            </script>
                            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('marriage')}" th:errors="*{marriage}">Marriage status error</span> 
                        </div>
                        
                        
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <label>  Employee Birthday </label>
                            <input type="date" th:field = "*{birthday}" name = "birthday" />
                            <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('birthday')}" th:errors="*{birthday}">Birthday error</span>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class = "container">
                            <div class = "form-group">
                                <label for="">  Employee Works at </label>
                                <select th:field = "*{workat}" class = "form-control"  name="workat" id="select1" onchange="populate(this.id,'select2')">
                                <option th:field = "*{workat}" value="">--SELECT COMAPNY--</option>
                                <option th:field = "*{workat}" value="NIC-Hyderabad">NIC-Hyderabad</option>
                                <option th:field = "*{workat}" value="NIC-Bangalore">NIC-Bangalore</option>
                                </select>
                                <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('workat')}" th:errors="*{workat}">Work at error</span>
                                
                                <div class = "form-group">
                                <label for="">Department</label>
                                <select th:field = "*{workat}" class = "form-control" name="workat" id="select2"></select>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                        
                            function populate(s1,s2)
                            {
                                var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
                                var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
                                
                                s2.innerHTML = "";
                                
                                if(s1.value == "NIC-Hyderabad")
                                    {
                                        var optionArray = ['dep-01|Dep-01','dep-02|Dep-02','dep-03|Dep-03',
                                            'dep-04|Dep-04'];
                                    }
                                else if(s1.value == "NIC-Bangalore")
                                    {
                                    var optionArray = ['dep-01|Dep-01','dep-02|Dep-02','dep-03|Dep-03'];
                                    }
                                for(var option in optionArray)
                                    {
                                        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
                                        var newoption = document.createElement("option");
                                        
                                        newoption.value = pair[0];
                                        newoption.innerHTML=pair[1];
                                        s2.options.add(newoption);
                                    }
                                
                            }
                        
                        </script>
   
   
        
                        <div class = "box-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class = "btn btn-primary">
                                Submit
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It might be that you are sending the request wrong. How does your form with the file input look like?

Comment: So you aren't submitting an image. How would changing the controller solve that? You need to change the code that is sending the request to this controller. So your form or javascript stuff on the client.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have added html form, please check.

Comment: `th:field` overrides the `name` the parameter is named `image` not `fileImage`. Either remove the `h:field` or rename your parameter in the controller.

Comment: @M.Deinum  after removing the th:field, it works. Thank you.